# How to find uncommon values from two arrays in java

Tags: java

I can able to find common values from two arrays using if condition and ==
but not able to find uncommon i mean to get unique values , please help me
to get uncommon values...

Common values : 3 i got expected output

Uncommon Values : 1 2 4 5  how to get != condition is not working

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {3,4,5};

void commonValues(){
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){
            if (a[i]==b[j]){
                System.out.println("Common values: "+a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the arrays sorted like yours are? Can there be duplicate values in an array?

Comment: Hi andreas 

two arrays i have declared to practice

i need to get output as 1 2 4 5   different values from two arrays  andreas

Answer (score 5):

Your code is *O(n^2)*, i.e. has bad performance characteristic for large arrays.

For better performance, use `Set` instead of array. `Set` then provides nice helper methods.

Here is example code (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations) for set operators):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {1,2,3};
    int b[] = {3,4,5};

    Set<Integer> setA = toSet(a);
    Set<Integer> setB = toSet(b);

    // common = A ∩ B
    Set<Integer> common = new TreeSet<>(setA); // use TreeSet for sorted result
    common.retainAll(setB); // intersection: ∩
    System.out.println("common: " + common);

    // uncommon = (A ∪ B) \ common
    Set<Integer> uncommon = new TreeSet<>(setA); // use TreeSet for sorted result
    uncommon.addAll(setB); // union: ∪
    uncommon.removeAll(common); // asymmetric difference: \
    System.out.println("uncommon: " + uncommon);
}
private static Set<Integer> toSet(int... arr) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(arr.length * 4 / 3 + 1);
    for (int v : arr)
        set.add(v);
    return set;
}
```

*Output*

```
common: [3]
uncommon: [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: hi Andreas in your code toSet method throwing errors such as
1. illegal modifier for parameter   2. arr cannot solved to be variable 
3. cannot return set asking to change

and why did you made this toSet method to convert array to set right what is the calculation while declaring HashSet not able to understand

Comment: @RaviNarayanan Varargs was added in Java 5, so I don't know what "illegal modifier for parameter" means, since there are no modifiers. --- Why did I make `toSet`? Because there are no built-in methods for creating a `Set<Integer>` from an `int[]`.

Comment: i am adding whole image of your code bro in above code plz check